# I want to deploy a file for an Android app to the Documents/MyApp folder using Embarcadero

Tags: android, delphi-10-seattle

I want to deploy an XML file with my Android application. I want to be able to move it after startup of the file to Done folder as I want to process the file only the first time I start the app.
I want to deploy the file to a folder under the Documents folder named after my app: /Documents/MyApp/Load/ and after finishing processing it move it to /Documents/MyApp/Done/.

I am using Delphi 10.

I can not figure out what I need to put in the Remote Path in the Deployment manager.

"assets" places the file in the /Android/data/com.test.MyApp/ folder and that is read-only so I can not move it away.

I think I have tried about anything accept the correct value...

Comment: Try `assets\internal` instead (`TPath.GetDocumentsPath`). That is your app's private folder that it can do pretty anything with. That folder belongs to your app installation and only your app can access it.

Comment: Thanks Remy, that pointed me in the correct direction.